# アップロードした SVG 画像が表示されない

Tags: html, svg

コーディングの学習をしているものです。
自分のパソコンでローカルにhtmlをgoogleのブラウザで見る時には、背景画像としてSVG画像が表示されてうまくいっています。
ところが、初めてFileZillaを使って自分で作ったものをアップして確認してみるとSVG画像が表示されてません。
原因がわからなかったのですが、この画像をPNGに変換して、再びアップしてみてみるとブラウザで確認できました。
どうしてSVG形式の画像は映し出されなかったのかわかりません。
もしかしたら、コードを書くときに階層の位置関係を間違えてしまったのかと考えましたが、それも違うようです。
このようにhtmlにコードを書いています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**画像を指定している箇所のHTML:**

```
    <!-- 背景画像 -->
    <!-- <div class="back">
      <img src="img/oval.png" alt="" />
    </div> -->
    <!-- 背景画像 -->
    <div class="back">
      <img src="img/oval.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
```

画像の階層はPNGもSVGも同じところにあり、階層の位置関係を間違えて書いているわけでもなさそうです。
ネットでFileZillaについて、また、SVG画像についての注意点なども調べてみましたがわかりませんでした。
どなたか、この画像が表示されない原因を教えてくださいませんか。

Comment: ファイルの一覧 (の画像) ではなく、HTML ファイルの内容をテキストのまま質問を編集して貼り付けてください。ファイルの一覧も途中で途切れていますが、SVG ファイルは正常にアップロードされているのかも確認してみてください。

Comment: SVGファイルが正常にアップロードされてるかの確認はどのようにするのですか？アップしたものをブラウザで見ると画像は確認できないのですが

Comment: <!-- 背景画像 -->
    <!-- <div class="back">
      <img src="img/oval.png" alt="" />
    </div> -->
    <!-- 背景画像 -->
    <div class="back">
      <img src="img/oval.svg" alt="" />
    </div>
テキストのままだとこのような感じでよろしかったでしょうか？ファイルが正常にアップロードされてるかの確認はどのようにするかがわかりません。ファイルジラでアップしたものを確認すると画像は表示されていないようなのですが

Comment: 質問はいつでも [edit] できるので、質問に関わる情報が直接追記してください。 / 正常にアップロード出来ているかについては、FileZilla であれば左右にローカルとリモートのファイル一覧が並んで表示されるはずなので、そちらの画面でアップロード出来ているかを確認してみてください。

Comment: ファイルジラでの左右のファイル一覧で見ると、ローカルからリモートにアップはされてるようです。

Comment: [Chrome not rendering SVG referenced via <img> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737166/)